# Copy Spreadsheet into specific folder in GDrive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I got an issue on DocsList... "DocsList is not deined"
Can anyone help ?

```
function myFunction() {

  //This part make a copy of the spreadshee
  var SSID = 'XXXXX' //Spreadsheet ID
  var CopyDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-3", "ddMMyyyyHHmm"); // Function Date + Format
  var folder = DocsList.getFileById('YYYYY'); //Get folder by ID
  var backup = DocsList.getFileById(SSID).makeCopy(SpreadsheetApp.openById(SSID).getName() + "_" + CopyDate);
  backup.addToFolder(folder); //This line will be move the folder
  backup.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder()); //This line is needed to remove the Filde from the Root

}
```

Answer (score 1):

### How to debug an Apps Script code

- When you get an Apps Script error, usually it tells you in which line it is located
- You did not mention the line in which the error occured, but I assume in your case it is `line 6`
- Your line 6 is `var folder = DocsList.getFileById('YYYYY');` and the error `DocsList is not defined`
- The reason is that `DocsList` is neither a variable defined in our code, nor an established Apps Script class or method
- [`getFileById()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid) is a method of the class [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app), and needs to be called as such: `DriveApp.getFileById('xxxxx')`